# Inverse-Transformation Method gives complex results

Tags: stochastic-processes, simulation

Given the following pdf
$$
f(x)=2x^{-3},\;\;\;1<x<\infty
$$
it seems nature to me to use the inverse-transformation method. find that
$$
F(x)=-x^{-2}
$$
and set
$$
x=-U^{-\frac{1}{2}}
$$
where $U\sim(0,1)$. However, this arrangement means all the $x$'s are complex since we have taking square root of a negative number. Is there any thoughts on what is going wrong here? Or inverse-transformation is simply not applicable here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cdf doesn't make sense, since it wants to calculate negative probabilities. Make sure you take the correct antiderivative $$\int_1^x f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t.$$

Comment: I agree with @user323524 A supplementary hint: an antiderivative is defined up to an additive constant that you have taken equal to 0...